# docker | unknown environment `bash` | sub process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, debian, containers, dpkg

My goal is to get a docker container running with nordvpn installed and connected.

**Get docker container going**

```
sudo docker pull ubuntu:latest
sudo docker run -it ubuntu bash
// now im in the docker container
apt install update
apt install wget
wget {{nordvpn_link.deb}}
dpkg -i {{nordvpn_link.deb}}
// some errors about dependencies after above command so ...
apt install -f
// then
apt install nordvpn
```

**First big error**

```
root@f706a3f4012f:/home# apt install nordvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nordvpn is already the newest version (3.6.0-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up nordvpn (3.6.0-2) ...
[ERROR] Unknown environment `bash'
dpkg: error processing package nordvpn (--configure):
installed nordvpn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
nordvpn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**I read [here](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/) to run the following command**

```
dpkg --configure -a
// errors
Setting up nordvpn (3.6.0-2) ...
[ERROR] Unknown environment `bash'
dpkg: error processing package nordvpn (--configure):
installed nordvpn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
nordvpn
```

I am not sure as to why this is happening with the docker container as the process went smoothly on my regular ubuntu desktop installation.

Comment: Do you meant `apt update` instead of `apt install update`?

Comment: After digging a bit deeper, I found the post installation script /var/lib/dpkg/info/nordvpn.postinst. It fails because systemd is not installed. What image are you running?

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen I have tried on `ubuntu:18.04` and `ubuntu:latest`; the error that pops out to me the most is `unknown environment bash`. I have never seen that before.

Comment: @MattClendenen I've changed my answer below to explain what's happening, apparently it's not so simple to get systemd running. I assume there must be an other solution to get nordvpn running inside a container.

Comment: btw, I have posed my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708051/run-nordvpn-in-a-docker-container but kept it a bit more open.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `systemd` is not running.

In the post installation script `/var/lib/dpkg/info/nordvpn.postinst` on line 5 it gets the name of the process with pid 1 `ENV=$(ps --no-headers -o comm 1)`, which is in your case `bash` and not `systemd`.

Later it evaluates `$ENV` and if the system was started with `systemd` (or `init`) it starts the nordvpn service, otherwise it returns `exit -1`.

See the snippet below:

```
case "$ENV" in
    init)
      # snip
    ;;
    systemd)
        # snip
        systemctl enable nordvpnd.socket &>/dev/null || :
        systemctl enable nordvpnd.service &>/dev/null || :
        systemctl start nordvpnd.socket &>/dev/null || :
        systemctl start nordvpnd.service &>/dev/null || :
    ;;
    *)
        echo "[ERROR] Unknown environment \`$ENV'"
        exit -1
    ;;
# snip
```

Similar question: [Run nordvpn in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708051/run-nordvpn-in-a-docker-container)