# Run nordvpn in a docker container

Tags: docker

I have a python script that I want to dockerize.

The script has to change the vpn connection to a different country by executing a shell command: 
`subprocess.call(["nordvpn", "c", country])`.

I have tried out the following, which doesn't work since systemd is not running. The post installation script of nordvpn (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/nordvpn.postinst`) needs `systemd` (or `init`) to be running:

```
 FROM python:3
 ADD vpn.py

 RUN pip install pandas

 RUN wget https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb -P /tmp \
     ; apt-get install /tmp/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb \
     ; apt-get update \
     ; apt-get install -y nordvpn 

 CMD [ "python3", "./vpn.py" ]
```

Are there any other ways to get this working?

I have thought about using the nordvpn binary of the host system, which would not be the neatest solution but for the moment ok.

Another possible solution would be to install nordvpn each time when starting the container but then systemd should be running, which is apparently not very easy to achieve.

Comment: If it's trying to manage the host's network configuration, and needs access to the host systemd, then it needs to run directly on the host and not in a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze it sounds like dockerizing such an application is not the way to go, is it possible to use the hosts nordvpn application?

Comment: Containers can't run processes on the host, or anywhere other than as subprocesses in their own container.  If a container process needs to communicate with something else it's almost always over a network channel.